# Show Hide elements table element in loop by jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, hide, show

I am a learner in Jquery coding, My task is to show/hide **TABLE** elements on clicking **SPAN** element. I tried with below mentioned Jquery code which is not working..

**HTML code is:**

```
foreach($array as $key => $arrValue) {
  <span id="link<?=$count?>">$key</span>
    <table id="tbl<?=$count?>">

      foreach($arrValueas $key => $value) {
           <tr><td>$value</td></tr>
      }
   </table>
}
```

**My Jquery code is:**

```
$(function(){
   // To open/close field's group div
   $("span").each(function (i){
      i++;
      $('#link' + i).click(function (i) {
          $('#tbl' + i).toggle(800);
      });
   });
});
```

**Pls avoid PHP open close tags issues in HTML code..**

Comment: And your problem is...? Please provide us with the generated html as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$(function(){
   $("span").each(function (i){

      (function(i) {

          $('#link' + i).click(function() {
              $('#tbl' + i).toggle(800);
          });

      }(i));

   });
});
```

you don't need to increment the variable with `i++` oyherwise you won't set the handler on the expected `link` element. `Each()` is already incrementing the variable `i`

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why is the click delegation wrapped in a function?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("span").each(function (){ 
    $(this).click(function () { 
        $(this).next('table').toggle(800); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. Matei Mihai, but i dont know why this is not working for me.. as i also agree with Fabrizio Calderan..

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to match two different element groups:

[**Here is jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/103/)

```
var thumbs = $('ul.thumbHolder li');
var bigImg = $('ul.imgHolder li');

thumbs.click(function() {
    var target = $(this).index();
    bigImg.each(function(i){
        if( i != target){
            $(this).fadeOut(300);
        }else{
            $(this).fadeIn(300);
        }
    });    
});​
```